# JAVA: JTabbedPane -- how do you reference the content pane?

Tags: java, jtabbedpane

I'm trying to reference the contents of a tabbed pane and NOT the tab itself. Every article i find on the matter only affects the tab and not the tab contents... im a bit lost. any help?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit and add some details (and code) maybe?

Comment: Once again post your SSCCE that demonstrates what you are attempting to do. People don't understand your question and are just quessing.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be manually putting anything in the content pane. The only access you should have to the content pane is by putting in sub panels in various index positions, using

```
    JTabbedPane.add(String title, Component component)
```

Obviously the sub component itself can be it's own JPanel, and you can add whatever you like to that panel.